# How to align navbar li with vertical align?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>De Studiehoek</title>
<LINK HREF="style/main.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">
<script src="/Javascript/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("scroll",function(){
if($(document).scrollTop()>50){
    $("header").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
} else{
    $("header").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
}
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<header  class=“large”>
<nav id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Welkom</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Informatie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Begeleiding</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Visie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</nav> <!--navbar-->
</header>


<section id="welkom">

<p> test tekst </p>
<p> en nog meer tekst <p> 
</section>

</body>
</html>

body { 
background-color: #0d1416;
}


header,nav, a, img, li{
transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition: all 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition: all 1s; /* Opera */
}

/*header*/
header {
background: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 0.9;
float: left;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 10;
}

header.a { 
color: #969696;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
font-size: 1em;
} 

header a.active{
color: #3d3d3d;
} 
header a.hover{ 
color: #FF00FF;
}

/* Sizes for the bigger menu */
header.large{
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 120px; 
}

header.large ul{
float: right;
}

header.large li{ 
display: inline;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

header.large a{ 
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Sizes for the smaller menu */
header.small{
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 50px; 
}

header.small ul{ 
float: right;
}


header.small li{ 
display: inline;
float: left;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 2px;
padding-right: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}

header.small a{ 
text-decoration: none;
}

/*section welkom*/
#welkom {
float:left;
height: 1500px;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}
```

I'm working on a project, but i'm stuck with a problem. My navbar had a changing size, I want the `<li>` to `vertical-align: middle;` but I don't know how to get it to work. Can someone help me out here? I tried to make it work by putting it in the `<li>` and I tried to place the text in a different class and than tried to make it vertical align, but neither worked.

Comment: i can't get it to work in a fiddle. you can view it on: http://destiny-craft.com the problem is the scrolling function.

Comment: you need to use display inline-block

Comment: okay, but where do i need to put the inline-block?

Comment: hmm, sorry i still don't get it. I need to use display: inline-block. That's what i make up out of your answer. But my question is where i need to put the display: inline-block in my css, on what place? i need to vertical center the text of my li in my navbar. so it's in the center at the small size header and the large size header.

Comment: see my answer it works just tried it on your website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify your code like this

```
header.large{
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 120px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: table; //imporatnt use this on your header.small also
}

#navbar{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want. vertical-align is for the inline elements (or text) within a block element. If you want a block element (like a nav tag) to be centered give it a left and right margin with a value of auto. If you want your li elements to be side by side set a display propperty with the value of inline-block

```
nav{
    margin:0 auto;
    /*Update: you must also give the nav a width for this to work*/
    width:450px;
}
nav li{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Update: After seeing your comment I think this is what you want

```
li {
    list-style:none;
}
li a {
    display: block; /*the links will now be displayed as block elements with a default width of 100% */
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It's for the text in the ul, sorry for that misunderstanding. If you want to see the script on a page: http://destiny-craft.com